Suffix-free padding scheme for hash function
I would like an easy to read proof that shows that it is sufficient for a padding scheme to be suffix-free for it to be collision resistant.
Whenever I have come across such a proof it always seems to be in the context of iterated constructions from compression functions, such as the Merkle-Damgård Construction. Why is this? Can such proofs be generalized?

Most, if not all, general-purpose cryptographic hash functions are iterated constructions from compression functions, which is probably why you see that context so frequently.  Not all are Merkle-Damgård, though.
